# function to scale up Wordpress images

Tags: wordpress

I found [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50649/how-to-scale-up-featured-post-thumbnail) great topic but am not allowed to comment due to my rep......
So I found myself forced to open this new topic (am I right?)

It states this code in order to scale up my images, it works perfectly!

```
function image_crop_dimensions($default, $orig_w, $orig_h, $new_w, $new_h,          $crop){
       if ( !$crop ) return null; // let the wordpress default function handle this

$aspect_ratio = $orig_w / $orig_h;
$size_ratio = max($new_w / $orig_w, $new_h / $orig_h);

$crop_w = round($new_w / $size_ratio);
$crop_h = round($new_h / $size_ratio);

$s_x = floor( ($orig_w - $crop_w) / 2 );
$s_y = floor( ($orig_h - $crop_h) / 2 );

return array( 0, 0, (int) $s_x, (int) $s_y, (int) $new_w, (int) $new_h, (int) $crop_w, (int) $crop_h );
}
 add_filter('image_resize_dimensions', 'image_crop_dimensions', 10, 6);
```

**however** It does not work for image sizes defined like this:

```
add_image_size( '800', 800 );
```

of course, cause there's no `$new_h` right?
how can I fix this function to work on `add_image_size( '800', 800 );` images?

Thanks!

**EDIT**
Changed my `add_image_size( '800', 800 );` to `add_image_size( '800', 800, 800 );` and it still does not work.
this is because `crop` is set to false, if I do this, `add_image_size( '800', 800, 800, true );` it works,
but I don't want the crop!
Thanks guys

Comment: The topic you've referred to, and the code you've provided, is to add a filter to the method `image_resize_dimensions`. To run the code, you need to call the `image_resize` method, not `image_crop_dimensions`. The argumens for `image_resize` are `string $file, int $max_w, int $max_h, bool $crop = false, string $suffix = null, string $dest_path = null, int $jpeg_quality = 90`

Answer (score -2):

The function add_image_size need numbers, in your code the first parameter is a String.

so if you replace '800' with 800, could work.

```
add_image_size( 800, 800 );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've set it to `add_image_size( '800', 800, 800 )` however, it still does not upscale it to 800 width with any height when I upload a 300x200 pixture

Comment: add Image size create, a thumbnail with the format that you choose. 

So if you use add_image_size("800", 800, 800), in your functions.php, in your template you have to call this thumbnail format with
the_post_thumbnail( '800' );

For older post it don't create automatically this format of thumbnail, but you can generate the new format using regenerate thumbnails plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

Comment: I know, thanks, I think you misunderstand my question, using the `add_image_size( 800, 800 )` with CROP set to False, does breaks my function described in my original question for that specific image size, how can I fix that